# Join() does not stop main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am using threads to collect som primes, in the end of the run() i update a local list with primes, in the main i try .join() all the threads, so they all finish their run() meaning their local list is full and then just append these values to an arraylist. but sometimes it works, other times not? seems like the appending happend before the threads fill the list, I am pasting the code:

```
class SieveWorker extends Thread {
    final int start, end, id;
    int[] localPrimes;

    SieveWorker(int start, int end, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
   .....
     @Override
    public void run() {
        
         ....Some code...

        //here we fill the list
        localPrimes=collectPrimes();
        //I get correct values everytime i print
        System.out.println("Local primes:\t" + Arrays.toString(localPrimes));
        .....End of run....

    }

    public int[] getLocal(){
        return localPrimes;
    }
```

This is how I start the threads and end them

```
    SieveWorker[] workers = new SieveWorker[num_of_threads];
    int end;
    int value_length = num / num_of_threads;
    int start = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; i++) {
        ...initilize values..

        workers[i] = new SieveWorker(start, end, i);
        new Thread(workers[i]).start();
    }

    //Will fill this with the local primes
    List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    
    //Thought this was gonna wait for them to stop?
    for (Thread thread : workers) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    //Get the lists
    for (SieveWorker worker : workers) {
        
            int[] localPrimes = worker.getLocal();
            for (int prime : localPrimes) {
                primeList.add(prime);
        
    }}
```

If anyone has any tips, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: `join` does cause the calling thread to block until the target thread finishes. How did you observe the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting a new `Thread` per `SieveWorker`. You should either use `SieveWorker` which is a `Thread`

```
 workers[i] = new SieveWorker(start, end, i);
 workers[i].start();
```

Or make `SieveWorker` extend Runnable and create a `Thread` with that worker as the task, and store each thread in another array `Thread[] threads = new Thread[num_of_threads];`. Afterwards join on the `threads[]` not `workers[]`.

```
 workers[i] = new SieveWorker(start, end, i);
 threads[i] = new Thread(workers[i]);
 threads[i].start();
```

Comment: The second approach should work fine. As you say, for simplicity above I've omitted that thread instances would need to be recorded such as with `Thread[] threads` or `List<Thread> threads` and the join loop obviously needs to be on `threads` not `workers`

Comment: Edited, hopefully that makes my intention clearer.

Comment: Deleted my previous comments. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what DuncG said,

A `Thread` is not a *thread.* A *thread* is an object in the operating system that executes your code. An instance of the `Thread` class is an object that your program can use to create and manage an operating system *thread.*

When your program creates some `t=new Thread(...)`, that does not create the OS *thread.* The OS *thread* isn't created until your program calls `t.start()`.

Your `SieveWorker` class `extends Thread`, but you never *use* your SieveWorker *as* threads because you never `start` them. You only use them as `Runnable` objects. (`Thread implements Runnable`, so therefore, your SieveWorker must also implement Runnable.) The actual *threads* in your program are created when you call `new Thread(workers[i]).start();`

Your actual problem is, your program doesn't save the new Thread objects. It saves the SieveWorker objects in the `workers` array, but the SieveWorker objects do not control the program's *threads.* You can `join` them, but that does nothing because they never were `start()`ed.